# Solutions of Elliptic PDEs: scaling and ellipticity

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have a weak solution of the uniformly elliptic equation $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n D_i(a_{i,j}(x)D_j u(x)) = 0$$

in all of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Where $a_{i,j}$ are bounded and measurable and $D_i$ represents the partial derivative with respect to $x_i$.

Consider the scaling $y=\frac{x}{r}$ for some $r>0$

Can I say that for all $r>0$,  $u(rx)$  is a (weak) solution of another elliptic equation with the same ellipticity constant, in the unit ball $B(0,1)$  ??

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by a solution in the unit ball for all $r>0$?

Comment: that defining $v(x)=u(rx)$ for $x\in $B(0,1)$, this is a solution to the PDE.

Comment: No, not unless the coefficients are invariant or otherwise nicely behaved under this scaling.

Comment: @Tomás I don't really understand, isn't it defined as normally with test functions compactly supported in the unit ball?

Comment: @RayYang mhh ok, do I need something like $a_{i,j}(rx)=a_{i,j}(x)$ ?
So I can't really get back to the unit ball from larger ones using scaling?

Comment: @Tomás the solution should be a function $v: B(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ .. do you think my $v$ is not? I thought it is just a scaled restriction of $u$!

Comment: Yes you are right, I misread you question, sorry.

Comment: @Tomás no worries, thanks for the help!

Comment: @RayYang I am thinking: v is not a solution of this equation, but can I say that it is a solution of an equation with matrix coefficients with the same ellipticity property?

Comment: Yes, Moritz, you can say it solves another equation with the same ellipticity.

Comment: @RayYang thank you very much! Since my scope is to apply Harnak's inequality this sufficies!

Answer (score 1):

Let $r>0$. By the chain rule, scaling $y=\frac{x}{r}$,  $$D_iu(x)=\frac{\partial u (x)}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial u(ry)}{\partial y_i}\cdot \frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_i}=\frac{1}{r} D_i u(ry) $$
Moreover, we define $b_{i,j}(x)=a_{i,j}(rx)$.

But $u$ is a solution of the equation in $B(0,r)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and the $a_{i,j}$ satisfy the ellipticity condition in $B(0,r)$ hence the $b_{i,j}$ satisfy the same condition in $B(0,1)$.

This gives that $v$ is a solution of the equation with $b_{i,j}$ as coefficents.

Can someone please tell me if they think that this makes sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. The ellipticity constant (understood as the supremum of ratios largest/smallest eigenvalues of coefficient matrix) is scale-invariant. So is Harnack's inequality.